# Netbeans show css variables as error

Tags: css, netbeans, ide

My Netbeans IDE show me error when I'm using css variables.
For example, this lines of code will return an error:

```
:root {
    --main-bg-color: #dad66f;
}

.title {
    color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

I found this solution online:
https://bugzilla-attachments-262769.netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=160370
But I don't know how to install this patch.
Anyone have idea how I can stop showing this code as an error?

Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately the fix you found has not yet been implemented since the status of that bug is still NEW (see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262769), and in any case that proposed patch was not intended to be applied by users of NetBeans.

Comment: Is there any update after 14 months? Should I just move to the newer version of NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked and in the current latest Netbeans IDE version(11.3) CSS variables are working fine.