# Bootstrap 4 :root color displays invalid property value

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I tried to use `bootstrap 4` :Root color property but i get error `invalid property value`

i also checked for bootstrap documentation and found nothing.

can someone help me how do i use `bootstrap 4 :root property`

check below snippet i tried to achieve but failed.

also not i get error in `netbeans`[image]

thanks in advance

```css
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  --primary: #007bff;
  --secondary: #6c757d;
  --success: #28a745;
  --info: #17a2b8;
  --warning: #ffc107;
  --danger: #dc3545;
  --light: #f8f9fa;
  --dark: #343a40;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
}

.frm-input:focus {
  border-color: --yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="frm-row">
  <input class="frm-input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
</div>
```

Comment: Netbeans doesn't seem to support CSS variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225680/netbeans-show-css-variables-as-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your syntax. Try this:

```
.frm-input:focus {
  border-color: var(--yellow);
}
```

Also, the :root selector (or pseudo-class) does not come with bootstrap 4, it is a CSS built in feature. You can read more about it in [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root). In brief, it refers to the document's root element. All in all, you are defining [CSS variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) for the document's root element, which has nothing to do with bootstrap.

Furthermore, Netbeans have not implemented the support for CSS variables yet, [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262769).

Comment: great it works but why do i get error in netbeans. please check my image addin in question.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used netbeans yet. As far as I know, some IDEs just don't support CSS variables.

Answer (score 1):

These are [CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#css-variables). Reference them with `var(--..)`. In your case it would be:

```
.frm-input:focus {
  border-color: var(--yellow);
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/I2WpYQe8oG

Also note: Netbeans doesn't currently support CSS variables. [Netbeans show css variables as error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225680/netbeans-show-css-variables-as-error)

---

Related: [CSS use color from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040545/css-use-color-from-another-class/49040761#49040761)